# SAS remove special characters from string

Tags: sas, compression

Good afternoon,
I have a data set with a list of first and last names. Some of these names for whatever reason have special characters in them which need to be removed. The field is in character format and I've tried to use the following to only keep the characters which are allowed and remove all others. However my results come back with blank values for all the names.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Data want; 
set have;
'Last Name'n=compress(last_name,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'- ","k");
'First Name'n=compress(first_name,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'- ","k");
drop last_name first_name;
run;
```

Comment: Show your log. Are you sure your input dataset has variables named `last_name` and `first_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED with example dataset

```
 Data have;
    INPUT last_name $ 1-14  first_name $;
    datalines;
    thomas*   James 
    Kory-Elk  Nick
    ^Shaffner Fun
    ;
 Run;

 Data want; 
   set have;
     Last_Name_New=compress(last_name,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-","kis");
     First_Name_New=compress(first_name,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-","kis");
    drop last_name first_name;
 run;
 /* 'k' keeps the characters in the list instead of removing them.
    'i'  ignores the case of the characters to be kept or removed.
    's' adds space characters (blank, horizontal tab, vertical tab, carriage return, line feed, and form feed) to the list of characters.*/
```

Comment: Look at my above edited solution. The problem seemed to be from the naming of your new variable for each first and last name.